# Hydrogen atom transfer between enantiomers of rac-1-phenylethanol

Tags: hydrogen, chirality

[image: HAT & DKR]

(Taken from *Dalton Trans.*, **2012,** *41,* 13423–13428. [DOI:10.1039/c2dt31781h](http://doi.org/10.1039/c2dt31781h))

I have difficulties understanding the hydrogen transfer in the image above. I always thought that hydrogen transfers followed the following formula:

$$\ce{X^. + H-Y -> X-H + Y^.}$$

I can't really see the connection between the picture and the formula. Is it the whole ethanol group that is transferred?

Comment: The hydrogen transfer is between the enantiomers. The dashed hydrogen is transferred in the picture.

Comment: Is there any more context provided as to how the racemisation occurs? Hydrogen atom transfer via a radical process seems plausible to me since the resultant hydroxybenzyl radical is quite stabilised, but you need something to take the hydrogen atom, since C-H bonds don't just fall apart and re-form spontaneously.

Comment: I think, a deprotonation/reprotonation mechanism would be even more plausible than implying radical formation ($420~\mathrm{kJ/mol}$). (CC @orthocresol)

Comment: Your image appears to be from this source: http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleHtml/2012/DT/c2dt31781h  It's good practice to cite or link to such source material when you use it in a question (or answer).

Comment: @Jan Imo a radical process would be more selective for the C-H bond (benzylic C-H ~370 kJ/mol) over the O-H bond (~440 kJ/mol) whereas an ionic deprotonation/reprotonation would happen at the O-H preferably. I don't know, though, that's just what I remember from lectures :) Of course, I'm not suggesting homolytic cleavage, I was thinking more of a reversible hydrogen atom abstraction by something else.

Comment: @CurtF. Sorry don't know much about this site yet, but you are correct i should have cited it porpperly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you continue reading the paper? :) The source is important and is what was needed to answer the question!

I'm just going to quote from it.

> In DKR [dynamic kinetic resolution] a chemical catalyst is added in order to racemize the enantiomers, ensuring that all the substrate can be utilized. [...] Highly successful catalysts are often Ru(II) complexes [...] The metal complex catalyses racemization by a hydrogen transfer mechanism (Scheme 2).

[image]

So, the supposed hydrogen transfer occurs via coordination to a metal, followed by β-hydride elimination. Readdition of the metal hydride across the opposite face of the resultant ketone (acetophenone in this case) produces the other enantiomer.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot... sorry i wasted your time. I'll double check any further source based questions in the future. Thank you

Comment: No problem, it was an interesting question.